# Get full path of a file stored in sharepint documentlibrary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, c#-4.0

I have a file stored in a sharepoint libarary like
        filePathAndName = "http://spstore/sites/appsitename/documentlibraryname/abc.xls"

I need to be able to open the the abc.xls file using
       byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePathAndName);

but i get an error stating. uri formats are not supported. How do I get the full path to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the file first. For example you could use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to send an HTTP request to the remote server and retrieve the file contents:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] file = client.DownloadData("http://spstore/sites/appsitename/documentlibraryname/abc.xls");
    // TODO: do something with the file data
}
```

Comment: My problem is not in reading the file, but getting the absolute path of the file...i get the uri formats not supported error

Comment: What full path? The file is stored on the web server.